# How to set second yAxis scale according to data from first yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have an odd request. My boss wants me to improve an existing chart with a second axis.
[image: Here is my existing chart]

The blue area must define the scale of the second axis, like a percentage of completion for the reading of the green area. **The 100% value must be at the maximum of the blue area**. I can collect the highest value of the blue area without any trouble, but I don't know how to set the properties of the second axis according to this value. The thing is that the second axis does not have any data associated, therefore, he isn't shown...

Any idea ?

PS : I tried to be as clear as possible, but maybe that was not the case. Don't hesitate to tell me if you need more explanations.

Comment: Quite confused. The 100% value of what should be the maximum of the blue area? What are the bars? What are the dotted lines? Unrelated? is your problem that you want labels for the 'Cleared %' y-axis?

Comment: Yes I want to display the ticks on the second axis, based on the value of the blue area. The blue area always have a max value, and I want the second axis to display a 100% ticks at the same Y coordinate. About the other elements of the chat (green area, dotted line, columns), I forgot to remove them before taking a screenshot, they are indeed unrelated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use axis.linkedTo to get a second axis and data formatters to get the data formatted as percentages.

I'm not modifying the series data, only changing the text shown in the second yAxis scale, the tooltip and the data labels.

```
yAxis: [{
    // Default options
}, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    opposite: true,
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return formatPercent(this.value);
        }
    }
}]
```

Example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uPHZx/

Comment: I'll try that and get back to you :p

Comment: It works great, but the problems is that this way, the ticks are synchronized between the 2 axes, and I can't get the 100% ticks, which is the most important. Any idea ?

Comment: You can add tickInterval to be the maxValue/5 so to get a tick on each 20%, http://jsfiddle.net/uPHZx/1/

Comment: It doesn't work on my computer, but that's not the problem. This way the ticks on the left axis are changed, and mine should stay the same. I found a solution to my problem : I made a new data serie, without any markers or line, connected to the second axis, and filled it with percentage data (`(currentValue/maxValue)*100`). With a few tweaks on the axis properties, it works. I'm giving you the bounty because you solution works too. Thanks for taking the time !